# .htaccess rewrite folders and parameters to parameters

Tags: apache, .htaccess, parameters, url-rewriting

i have this example:

[www.mysite.com/**folder1/folder2/folder3/..etc..**/index?**par1=321321323&par2=321312323&..etc..*](http://www.mysite.com/**folder1/folder2/folder3/..etc..**/index?**par1=321321323&par2=321312323&..etc..*)*

I want redirect and rewrite to:

[www.mysite.com/index?**f1=folder1&f2=folder2&f3=folder3&..etc..&par1=321321323&par2=321312323&..etc..*](http://www.mysite.com/index?**f1=folder1&f2=folder2&f3=folder3&..etc..&par1=321321323&par2=321312323&..etc..*)*

with file .htaccess apache

You can help me!!!?

Comment: Sure. But for us to help fix your implementation you need to post your implementation. How else do you expect is to help with that? Or did you mean that we do your work for you? Sorry, but that is not how this site works. You are expected to implement the solution yourself, that is when we can help.

Comment: But in this case there are 2 or 3 rows of code to implement... there isn't C#, javascript or other languages that i can write something... Here we have a 'configuration' to do. I know nothing about instruction, regex or other about .htaccess. I hope that you can help me for this particular question. Thanks

Comment: You will find literally _thousands_ of examples here in SO. I am sure you can adapt those for your purpose, at least attempt to. And there is a documentation, as typical for OpenSource it is of excellent quality and also comes with great examples: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html
In the end we have to work our way into new fields all the time. That is exactly _why_ it is so important to do it yourself: to learn.